# Socket Hangup error when CA Certificate(.pfx file) attached to postman request for dotnet core web api

Tags: asp.net-core, ssl, postman, x509certificate, client-certificates

I Need to attach a CA certificate with the postman request. I am attaching a CA certificate as shown in this in postman [CA certifcate image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/29xRj.png). Here domain.pfx is not a self-signed certificate. It is signed by CA. When I attach this certifcate and hit the dotnet core web api controller, It is giving the socket hangup error. Its not even hitting dotnet core web api. Giving this error in postman.[error_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5wHO.png)[error details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/He6Up.png).

But When I attach the self-signed certificate instead of a certificate signed by CA, everything works as expected. I can hit the controller and retrieve thumbprint from it. I am attaching the self-signed certificate in the same way.[self-signed-certificate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7UEm.png)

I am getting the socket hangup error only when a CA certificate is attached, with Self-Signed certificate its working. How can I resolve this issue? Am I doing something wrong in adding CA certificate? Is there any other ways to attach a CA certificate in postman?

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration of the certificate does not appear to be a problem. Since I don't know what your request looks like, I can only share with you a few cases where I encountered this error.

1. When you use same port for connecting database, which port is already in use for other service, then "Socket Hang up" error comes out. For example: port 51223 is dedicated port for some other service or connection. You cannot use same port (51223) for making a database connection on same server.
2. Your application was switched to https and your postman requests still had http in them. You can change postman to https to fix it.
3. Check if there is a VPN connection, if so, disconnect it.
4. Check if the version of postman is the latest version, this problem occurs in some versions.

Hope this can help you.